# SAML2 and role {urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata}SPSSODescriptor wasn't found

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0

while creating new Service Provider meta data i'm getting below error:

org opensaml saml2 metadata provider MetadataProviderException : Metadata for entity urn:com:saml:poc:tshah and role {urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata}SPSSODescriptor wasn't found

I have default/template SP metadata file with application

Security-Config.xml file structure as below

I have already followed steps provided by some of previous posts.

```
            <!-- SP (current application) Metadata configuration -->
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.ResourceBackedMetadataProvider">
                        <constructor-arg>
                            <bean class="java.util.Timer"/>
                        </constructor-arg>
                        <constructor-arg>
                            <bean class="org.opensaml.util.resource.ClasspathResource">
                                <constructor-arg value="${spring.security.saml.sp.metadata.file.location}"/>
                            </bean>
                        </constructor-arg>
                        <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                        <property name="local" value="true"/>
                        <property name="alias" value="TestSAML"/>
                        <property name="securityProfile" value="metaiop"/>                  
                        <!-- <property name="sslHostnameVerification" value="allowAll"/>  -->                   
                        <property name="signMetadata" value="false"/>
                        <property name="signingKey" value="${spring.security.saml.java.keystore.cert.alias}"/>
                        <property name="encryptionKey" value="${spring.security.saml.java.keystore.cert.alias}"/> 
                        <property name="requireArtifactResolveSigned" value="false"/>
                        <property name="requireLogoutRequestSigned" value="false"/>
                        <property name="requireLogoutResponseSigned" value="false"/>
                        <property name="idpDiscoveryEnabled" value="false"/>                            
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>   

        </list>
    </constructor-arg>

    <!-- OPTIONAL used when one of the metadata files contains information about this service provider -->
    <property name="hostedSPName" value="urn:com:saml:poc:tshah"/>
    <!-- OPTIONAL property: can tell the system which IDP should be used for authenticating user by default. -->
    <!-- <property name="defaultIDP" value="http://localhost:8080/opensso"/> -->
</bean>
```